# how to replace a substring in a list of strings in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

so I'm using beautifulsoup to crawl a table in a Wikipedia page in which I extract data in a file.
the problem is that I want to remove some of the substrings in the list generated for the columns in the table

here is my code:

`soup= bs(result.text,'html.parser')`

`country_names= soup.find('table', class_= 'wikitable sortable').tbody`

```
rows= country_names.find_all('tr')
columns=[v.text.replace('[a][b][13]\n', '') for v in rows[0].find_all('th')]
print(columns)
```

all I was able to do is to remove only one substring from the strings in the list using a replace function.

**the output before `replace()` function:**

```
['Flag\n', 'Map\n', 'English short nameandformal name[6][7][8]\n', 'Local short name(s)andformal name(s)[6][7]\n', 'Capital[8][9][10]\n', 'Population (2018)[11][12]\n', 'Area[a][b][13]\n']
```

**the output after `replace()` function:**

```
['Flag\n', 'Map\n', 'English short nameandformal name[6][7][8]\n', 'Local short name(s)andformal name(s)[6][7]\n', 'Capital[8][9][10]\n', 'Population (2018)[11][12]\n', 'Area']
```

so I want to remove all substrings such as `'[8][9][10]\n'`, `' [6][7]\n '`, `'[6][7][8]\n'` and `'(2018)[11][12]\n'` and so on but I couldn't reach a solution because I'm still new to python and beautifulsoup.

Comment: The question doesnt have anything to do with beautiful soup or web-crawling :). I think you can remove that part of the question (and tags).

Comment: The question isn't actually "how to replace a substring in a list of strings in python?", since you already showed code that does exactly that: you have a list of strings, and you successfully replace the substring `[a][b][13]` in each string that contains it. The *question* is how to replace *any substring that matches a pattern*; clearly, once you have that tool, you already know how to apply it to a list. (You also apparently know how to work with BeautifulSoup and list comprehensions.) It is helpful to ask the question that you actually need help with.

Comment: It is also helpful to create examples that *focus on* that question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: But once you are asking the question that you actually have, it is much easier to [research](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+replace+substring+matching+pattern) it (as is [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python `re` regular expression library for this. The `re` library has a function `re.sub(pattern,replace_string,input_string)` that will replace any substring that matches the pattern regular expression.

Something like this:

```
# make sure to import the re module
import re

columns = [re.sub('(\[[a-zA-Z\d]*\])+\n','',v.text) for v in rows[0].find_all('th')]
```

Edit: Changed the regular expression pattern

Comment: I tried this but cannot be applied on the whole list, sum strings still have the parts that should be eliminated in the pattern. is there a way to add other conditions in the pattern?

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely add other things to the pattern. What else are you trying to replace?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to dive deeper into Regular Expressions:

Use e.g. `\[\d+\]` as expression for any number of digits inside brackets.

```
import re
org_string = 'Capital[8][9][10]\n'
pattern = r'\[\d+\]'
mod_string = re.sub(pattern, '', org_string )
# Capital
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution you are looking for:

```
import re
colums = [re.sub('(\[[0-9]+])', '', i).replace('\n', '') for i in rows]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So how can I eliminate the [a] and [b] as well or any additional substring I want. can I add additional conditions I want to eliminate in the `sub()`? or does it hold only one pattern? also, how I get the right pattern or the syntax for it correctly as I searched but couldn't find the right way

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output requires the use of regular expressions inside a list comprehension:

```
import re

list_before = ['Flag\n', 'Map\n', 'English short nameandformal name[6][7][8]\n', 'Local short name(s)andformal name(s)[6][7]\n', 'Capital[8][9][10]\n', 'Population (2018)[11][12]\n', 'Area[a][b][13]\n']

pattern = r'(\(\d+\))*(\[\w+\])*\n?'

list_after = [re.sub(pattern, "", elem).strip() for elem in list_before]
```

the `pattern` defines the regular expression pattern that you want to substitute in each string of the `list_before`. You may want to dig deeper into regular expressions to fully understand it, but in plain English this pattern matches:

- 0 or more occurrences of "(", followed by 1 or more digits (which are indicated by the special sequence `\d`), followed by ")"
- 0 or more occurrences of "[", followed by 1 or more alphanumeric characters (which are indicated by the special sequence `\w`), followed by "]"
- 0 or one occurrences of the new line `\n`

finally, the method `re.sub()` inside the list comprehension replaces any match with "".

the output is:

```
['Flag', 'Map', 'English short nameandformal name', 'Local short name(s)andformal name(s)', 'Capital', 'Population', 'Area']
```